# Android app cache required storage permissions

Tags: android, caching

I have some confusion for the android cache, at run time android app cache required external storage read and write permissions or not. can any one help me for this confusion. For example,

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("img", ".png", getExternalCacheDir());
String imgPath = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Storage permission

```
    private static final int REQUEST_STORAGE = 112;



  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_STORAGE );
        } else {

            File tempFile = File.createTempFile("img", ".png", getExternalCacheDir());
            imgPath = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    } else {

        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("img", ".png", getExternalCacheDir());
         imgPath = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

get Permissions Result

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                   File tempFile = File.createTempFile("img", ".png", getExternalCacheDir());
                   imgPath = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask permission at runtime https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html, Example,

```
public void requestPermissionForExternalStorage() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
}
```